# Loop over dictionary list and retrieve values in django

Tags: python, arrays, django, dictionary

I am new to Python/Django, coming from PHP, and have difficulty understanding the best way to deal with what I am used to calling multidimensional arrays in PHP. So I have a CSV file:

```
name,age,phone
marta,30,12345
bob,22,33555
alice,55,1939
```

In my model, I'm reading this CSV file line by line. I will then analyze the code, manipulate some of the data, and then I want to display the data in a table. Here is what I do:

```
    data = {}
    with open(path) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        i = 0
        for row in reader:
            i += 1
            data[i] = {'name': row[0], 'age': row[1], 'phone': row[2]}
```

This seems to work and it creates a variable that contains all the rows, plus all the info for each row.

My idea, for better or for worse, is to get this list:

```
data[1] = {name: marta, age: 30, phone: 12345}
data[2] = {name: bob, age: 22, phone: 33555}
data[3] = {name: alice, age: 55, phone: 1939}
```

Which I then pass onto my view, where I do something like this:

```
      {% for details in data %}
        <tr>
          <td>{{ details.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ details.age }}</td>
          <td>{{ details.phone }}</td>
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}
```

The loop is successful and I am getting all the items, but the actual values (details.XXXXX) are blank. I've tried this: `details|get_item:name` but that gives an error (VariableDoesNotExist). I'm not sure if this nested dictionary is what I should be using or if I'm confusing the different lists etc. due to my PHP background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined `data` as dictinary: `data = {}`. But it supposed to be a list: `data = []`:

```
data = []
with open(path) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        data.append({'name': row[0], 'age': row[1], 'phone': row[2]})
```

In case of dictionary `{% for details in data %}` will return only dict's keys `0, 1, 2, 3` not data itself.

Comment: Ahhhh yes!! I've been stuck for a while, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

When you iterate dict this way:

```
for details in data:
    ...
```

Basically, you loop through dict keys (not values), so all what you need to do is:

```
{% for key, details in data.items %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ details.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ details.age }}</td>
      <td>{{ details.phone }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

or you could just use a list:

```
data = []
with open(path) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        data.append({'name': row[0], 'age': row[1], 'phone': row[2]})
```

and in the template - no changes from what you have for now

Comment: Thanks, I saw the previous answer earlier but this sorts it out indeed.